# How to select checked item in data Grid using linq

Tags: vb.net, linq

i have a `data grid` (using component one's control) and this data grid have a `check box` value item to select some of the rows, the given below is my grid
[image]

- i use the check box to select rows for `delete` or `update`
- at this moment am using `for` loop to iterate through my grid
- i think in `.net` using `linq` is more better than `for loop`

*given below is my code to iterate through grid using for loop*

```
Private Sub deleteGtab81()
    Dim intcount As Integer
    Dim intdistid As Integer
    Dim command, commandReader As New NpgsqlCommand
    command.Connection = GenConnection()
    commandReader.Connection = command.Connection
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    commandReader.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    For intcount = 0 To grdDistricts.Rows.Count - 1
        If grdDistricts(intcount, "S").ToString <> "" Then
            If grdDistricts(intcount, "S").ToString = 1 Then
                intdistid = grdDistricts(intcount, "talukid").ToString()
                command.CommandText = "delete from gtab81 where talukid='" & intdistid & "'  "
                command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End If
        End If
    Next
    grdDistricts.Rows.Clear()
    FillGrddistricts()
    FillCbodistricts()
End Sub
```

So how to use `linq` to get the selected rows ?

NOTE : code is written in `vb.net`

T.I.A

Comment: Post your `for` loop code to give more specific context to this question

Comment: @har07 i have included the for loop code

Comment: I think this question would be better posted @ http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @dna2 how to post the same question in CR to avoid duplicate ?

Answer (score 0):

I've never really tried to use LINQ against a DataGridViewRowCollection, but I suppose you should write something like that:

**C#**

```
IList<int> result = (from row in grdDistricts.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>() 
                        where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells["S"].Value.ToString()) &&
                              (int)row.Cells["S"].Value == 1 
                        select (int)row.Cells["talukid"].Value).ToList();
```

**VB.NET**

```
Dim list As IList(Of Integer) = (From row In grdDistricts.Rows.OfType(Of DataGridViewRow)() _
                Where Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells("S").Value.ToString()) AndAlso _
                        row.Cells("S").Value = 1 _
                Select DirectCast(row.Cells("talukid").Value, Integer)).ToList()
```

This will select all yours "talukid" and place them in a list.